# Ember component wont use extended class

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs

i have a problem with ember. Im trying to create a component but ember wont use my own component class.

```
// ------- main

require( ["handlebars", "ember"], function() {

    app = Ember.Application.create( {
        LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
        LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
        LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
        LOG_BINDINGS: true,
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true 
    });         

    require(["js/components/rsa-key.js"], function() {

        app.Router.map( function() {
            this.resource('application', { path: "/" });
        });                                 

    });             


});
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

    <h1>Title: {{title}}</h1>
    {{rsa-key}}
</script>     

// ---------- rsa-key-component
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/rsa-key">

<div class="controls-row">
//.....         
            <label for="storageLoadKey" class="col-lg-2 control-label" {{ action "toggle" }} >Local storage: </label>
//.....
</div>

</script>
// ---------- rsa-key.js
define([], function( ) { 

    app.RsaKeyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({  
        tagName: "nav",
        actions: {

            toggle: function() {
                alert("toggle");
            },
            localSave: function() {

                alert("save");
            }
        }

    });


});
```

The strange thing is that if i remove the "require("rsa-key.js")" and replace it with the content of it it works like a charm.

So the question is why doesent it work if i load it via require js?